# How to set focus onto the first form control of a dynamic FormArray?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a dynamic form array that I use to create a master-detail form for my project. My Form Array has been declared as follows, along with the functions to add and delete the elements of the array at the particular index 'i'.

items.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('item') item!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

constructor(){
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    itemArray: new FormArray([]),
  });
}

addItem() {
  const item= new FormGroup({
    itemCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    itemDesc: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    itemLoc: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    itemQty: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    itemUnit: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    itemPrice: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });
  this.items.push(stockIssue);
  this.item.last.nativeElement.focus();
}

deleteItem(index: number) {
  this.items.removeAt(index);
  this.item.last.nativeElement.focus();
}

get items(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('itemArray') as FormArray
}
```

items.component.html:

```
...
<div class="col-12">
  <table class="table table-sm table-borderless table-hover table-responsive" formArrayName="itemArray" >
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-reflow" style="background-color: rgb(25, 129, 129); color: white;">
         <th>Item Code</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Location</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Unit</th>
         <th>Price</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody (keydown.alt.n)="addItem()">
        <tr #item *ngFor="let itemof items.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i" (keydown.alt.x)="deleteItem(i)">
          <td>
            <input #itemCode class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" formControlName="itemCode">
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea #description class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="itemDesc" type="text"></textarea>
          </td> 
          <td>
             <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" formControlName="itemLoc">
          </td>                     
          <td>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" formControlName="itemQty">
          </td>
          <td>
             <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" formControlName="siUoM">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" formControlName="itemPrice">
          </td>
          <td>
             <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="deleteItem(i)">&#10005;</button>
          </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="addItem()">&#43;</button>
</div>
```

How do I set the focus onto the #itemCode input field of the last row every time a new formGroup is added or deleted from the FormArray?

I have made use of earlier solutions found here to previous questions, however I tend to get errors for them, such as for the above code when I have used `this.item.last.nativeElement.focus();`, I get:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of undefined
> at ItemComponent.addItem

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
> at ItemComponent.addItem

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of undefined
> at ItemComponent.deleteItem

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
> at ItemComponent.deleteItem

How do I resolve this issue?